# How to reset PostgreSQL / pgAdminIII password in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, postgresql

My friend is trying to log on to pgAdminIII on his iMac running OS X Yosemite.  He has two versions of PostgreSQL on his machine: 8.4 and 9.4.  He has lost his password.  How to reset the pgAdminIII password?

Comment: Your friend  lost the password for the PostgreSQL DB servers.  pgAdminIII has not any separate passwords but is only an interface to the DB server.

Comment: And the answer is here: http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2009/06/postgresql-how-to-reset-user-name.html

Comment: Where is pg_hba.conf?

Comment: I could not work out how to hack the password.   It seems stupid that you can't change the password via the system preferences.  So I think we'll be reinstalling PostgreSQL on my friends iMac.  But we'll back up his system first in the unlikely situation that there is some software that is using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have the following line in the pg_hba.conf file:

```
local   all         postgres
```

So I do not know where to put the line:

```
local   all         postgres                          trust same user
```

In what column does the "trust same user" go?

This is what is at the bottom of his pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```